# How can I get the text from the dynamic textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I have used this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int page_valid = i + 1;
    this.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Name = i.ToString(), Location = new Point(33, 210 + (i * 26)), Text = "" + page_valid + "." + " " + "Individual entrepreneur ", Size = new System.Drawing.Size(630, 20) });
}
```

How can I get the text from the dynamic textbox?

Comment: `TextBox.Text`? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Loop through the controls on the form and look for a textbox with name you are looking for.  Once you find it you can access its text property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it via it's name

```
string text = this.Controls["1"].Text;
```

If you wanna get the all texts you can use:

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(t => t.Text).ToArray();
```